# laravel - How to handle two methods in single view

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to place a dynamic banner section on All pages while content also coming from respective methods on all relevant pages suppose home page getting data from method index and about page getting from about method:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $pages = Page::where('slug', 'home')->first();
      return view('home', compact('pages'));
    }
   public function index()
    {
      $pages = Page::where('slug', 'about')->first();
      return view('home', compact('pages'));
    }
}
```

but at the same time i want to get a banner data from database on all pages section like:

this dyanamic banner section required on all pages. so how i will pass data into this section and then will include that section into all views?

```
@section('banner')
how can i get data here, using new method banner? how is it possible to pass data to a section. but not to home view?
@endsection


@section('content')
All pages content coming already here from respective methods.
@endsection
```

Comment: You need to read up on ComposerServiceProvider for achieving this. I utilise it myself on numerous projects - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers

Comment: i edited my question please recheck.

Comment: How about an `@include`?

Comment: i used include option too but issue is that how can i pass data from controller to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference for this would be a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers). Whenever I need a repeated element on a page and/or some specific logic for an element, it seems like the best choice for me.

You'd essentially do the following:

1. Add a new `ComposerServiceProvider`
2. Add a `banner` composer reference in the `boot()` method of your new service provider.

`View::composer(
    'banner', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\BannerComposer'
);`

3. Add the data needed for your banner blade file in `BannerComposer@compose`
4. Now in your blade layout file, or in any other blade files, you can `@include('banner')` to show the shared composer, which will include the data to render the template as well as the specific markup for the banner.

Comment: i cant vote because i have less points. otherwise i upvote your answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi so you have few options.

One is to send all you data i.e both banner and content from the controller to the view. so you will have something like this:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $pages = Page::where('slug', 'home')->first();
      $someData = 'got this from the db';

      return view('home', [
                'pages' => $pages,
                'banner_data' => $someData
           ]);
    }
}
```

Another approach is to blade injection. so it will look like this

```
@section('banner')
   @inject('VariableName', 'Some\Class\Path')

   {{ $VariableName->getData() }}

@endsection
@section('content')
home page content coming already from index method
@endsection
```